# Duvida em código C estrutura de dados

Tags: c, struct

Boa tarde, bom estou aqui pra ver se alguém sabe o porque que o meu código está printando um lixo de memória, quando execultado ele mostra oque eu quero porém printa um lixo de memória, se alguém souber o porque agradeço

[image: esses numeros ai "7304688"]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct no

int codigo;
char nome[10];
struct no *next;
}no;

struct no *corrente, *auxiliar, *inicio;

int i;

int inserir (no *lista)
{
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        if(auxiliar==NULL){
            auxiliar = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
            auxiliar->next = NULL;
            corrente = auxiliar;
            inicio = auxiliar;
        }
        else{
            auxiliar = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
            corrente->next=auxiliar;
            auxiliar->next = NULL;
            corrente = auxiliar;
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Entre com o codigo:\n");
            scanf("%d",&auxiliar->codigo);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Entre com o nome:\n");
            scanf("%s",&auxiliar->nome);
        }
    }
}



int exibir(no *lista)
{

    if(inicio==NULL){

        printf("Lista Vazia\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else{
        corrente = inicio;
        //system("cls");
        //printf("\tDados a ser mostrados...");
        //sleep(5);
        //system("cls");


        while(corrente!=NULL){

            printf("%d\n",corrente->codigo);
            printf("%s\n",corrente->nome);
            corrente = corrente->next;

        }
        system("pause");
    }
}

int main (){

    auxiliar = NULL;
    corrente = NULL;
    inicio = NULL;
    int tecla=1;


    printf("Programando dinamicamente:\n");
    printf("Aplicando encadeamento...\n");

    while(tecla!=0){
        printf("Digite\n \n1-Inserir \n2-Mostrar\n");
        scanf("%d",&tecla);


        switch(tecla){
            case 1: inserir(&inicio);
            break;
            case 2: exibir(&inicio);
            break;
            default: printf("Opcao Invalida");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Olhando por cima já vi que não está inicializado memória para a variável, pode ter outros erros. O código está confuso e desorganizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por onde começar?

Em primeiro lugar, **evite usar variáveis globais sempre que puder**. Particularmente, definir uma global `int i` para usar como índice de *loop* é se meter numa confusão infinita, já que você sempre tem que lembrar se alguma outra função que está chamando a sua função atual usa essa mesma variável para controlar um *loop* seu. Como aqui só a `inserir()` usa a variável `i`, isso por enquanto não vai acontecer, mas ao mesmo tempo é injustificável ela ser global se só uma função deve enxergá-la.

Em segundo lugar, na hora de fazer `scanf()`, sempre comece a *string* de formato com um espaço para que o CRT "coma" caracteres extras como retornos de carro. Quando estiver lendo uma string, **sempre use o especificador de precisão** para que o *buffer* não estoure: então `scanf(" %.9s", &(auxiliar->nome));` na linha 35, por exemplo (note que estamos mandando escrever *no máximo* 9 carecters, para que o décimo contenha o '\0').

Em terceiro, você passa um parâmetro `no * lista` tanto para `inserir()` quanto para `exibir()`, e depois ignora solenemente os parâmetros que passou em favor das referências globais `*inicio`, `*corrente` e `*auxiliar`. Crie em vez disso uma variável local de tipo `no *` e use-a no lugar de `corrente`, inicializando-a com o valor de `inicio` no princípio da função.

Tem outras coisas, mas nada disso faz o seu código imprimir o lixo. O que faz é a `inserir()`: você reparou que ela tem um *loop* `for(i=1;i<=3;i++)`, mas quando você roda a opção 1 pela primeira vez ele só pede **dois** nomes?  Vamos fazer um chinês da inserir:

1. Começa a função. `i = ???, inicio = NULL, corrente = NULL, auxiliar = NULL`.
2. Entra no *loop*. `i = 1, inicio = NULL, corrente = NULL, auxiliar = NULL`.
3. *if*: como `auxiliar == NULL`, entra-se no "then".
4. aloca-se o `auxiliar`. `i = 1, inicio = NULL, corrente = NULL, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = ??? }`.
5. seta-se o `auxiliar->next`. `i = 1, inicio = NULL, corrente = NULL, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }`.
6. seta-se o `corrente`. `i = 1, inicio = NULL, corrente = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }`.
7. seta-se o `inicio`. `i = 1, inicio = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, corrente = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }`.
8. termina-se o *loop*, incremento, teste. *Loop* continua. `i = 2, inicio = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, corrente = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }`.
9. `auxiliar != NULL`, então vai-se para o `else`. `i = 1, inicio = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, corrente = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }`.
10. Aloca-se um novo `auxiliar`, sem dado nenhum. `i = 1, inicio = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, corrente = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = NULL }, auxiliar = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = ??? }`.
11. seta-se o `corrente->next` para o novo `auxiliar` e depois começa-se a preencher os seus campos. `i = 2, inicio = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = &auxiliar }, corrente = { .codigo = ???, .nome = ???, next = &auxiliar }, auxiliar = { .codigo = 1234, .nome = "joao", next = NULL }`.

Consegue ver o padrão? O primeiro *link* da lista não teve nem `codigo` nem `nome` inicializados. Então ele imprime o lixo que estava na `codigo` e o lixo que estava na `nome` (no meu caso, graças a Deus, ele encontrou imediatamente um byte 0 e imprimiu uma *string* vazia.

O que fazer, então?

Refaça a sua `inserir` para testar a existência do `auxiliar`**antes** de entrar no *loop*, e aí carregue as informações em todas as iterações do `for`. Assim ele vai parar de inserir lixo.

Comment: Nossa cara que demais, Muito obrigado mesmo !!